# What is $\operatorname{Hom}((S^1)^k , (S^1)^n)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, continuous-homomorphisms

**I am trying to find $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm gp}((S^1)^k , (S^1)^n)$ , which is the set of continuous group homomorphisms from the $k$ dimensional torus to the $n$ dimensional torus where $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$.**

This is the **hint** I was given - first show that when $k = n = 1$, $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm gp}(S^1,S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Here is what I have managed to do -

1. Now, for a fixed $m \in \mathbb{Z}$  one can define a map $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ by $ f(z) = z^m$, but I don't know how to show that any homomorphism from $S^1$ to $S^1$ is of this form.
2. Assuming $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm gp}(S^1,S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ I have shown that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm gp}(S^1,(S^1)^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, that is, I have shown that  any homomorphism from $S^1$ to $(S^1)^n$ is of the form $z \mapsto (z^{h_1}, \dots ,z^{h_n})$ for some $n$ tuple $(h_1, \dots, h_n)$ and viceversa.
3. My guess is that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm gp}((S^1)^k,(S^1)^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right)}$, but assuming this guess is correct I have no idea how to proceed.

Please help.

Comment: $\hom(G,H)$ behaves somewhat like multiplying $G$ and $H$ - it *distributes* over finite direct sums (in both arguments), the same way multiplication distributes over addition. So we have $$\hom\left(\bigoplus_i G_i,\bigoplus_j H_j\right)=\bigoplus_i\bigoplus_j\hom(G_i,H_j),$$ which is exactly analogous to $$\left(\sum_i a_i\right)\left(\sum_j b_j\right)=\sum_i\sum_j a_ib_j. $$

Comment: Oh so that means $Hom ((S^1)^k, (S^1)^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{nk}$ correct?

Comment: Right. Anyway, are you sure the exercise doesn't specify *continuous* group homomorphisms?

Comment: @anon I just realized it myself and added continous. Thanks!

Comment: To complete the nice comment of @anon, $\mathrm{hom}\left(G,H\right)$ behaves like multiplying $G$ and $H$ because, in finite dimension, $\mathrm{hom}\left(G,H\right)\simeq G^*\otimes H$, and the tensor product ditributes over direct sum.